# HTML Table display in mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 2 tables that I am trying to show on a mobile device.  One has 2 columns and the other has 3 columns.  Here is the 2 column table:

[image]

I want the table to fill the whole screen.  Here is an example:

[image]

What is the css that will make this happen.  I am not interested how this displays on a normal monitor, but if I could get some direction on making this responsive then that would be great.  Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width attribute for each column, so that it adds up to 100%.. For example:
    column 1: width="50%" 
    column 2: width="20%" 
    column 3: width="30%"

Same thing for the table with two columns, set one for 80%, the other to 20%.. (you can play around with all these values, the important part is, it needs to add up to 100%)